# How to customize an openshift repo

Tags: openshift

I have read stuffs about Openshift cartridge and I still can't see how to just customize repo for Openshift like this one for WP https://github.com/openshift/wordpress-example

I clone that repo on my local machine and I'd like to just add some new plugins. Can someone explain or point me to an article to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They've updated their wordpress cartridge from https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/applications I guess after so many people were interested in having it scale they tweaked it a bit so it could, when they did they made it a little too easy it seems.

When you clone an application created from the standard cartridge (scaled or not) all your plugins and themes should be added in 
`/.openshift`. Important to note you don't use .zip files in these folders, you'll have to extract your plugins and themes them and drop those in the appropriate folder.

I'm not sure if they've designed this cartridge to upload plugins to this same directory from within wordpress*.

I'm also not so certain if they dealt with uploading media so that can scale as well.

What I do know is that after going through this you'll find wordpress up and running and if you load-test it you'll see (if you check /haproxy-status) that multiple gears will start up.